# Wordpress theme with frontend in different language than backend?

Tags: localization, language

I have added the po and mo files via Poedit for Chinese to my wordpress site.  I would like to keep my backend in English. How can this be achieved?  Is this possible without using a plugin such as Polylang?
[image: English Wordpress Admin plugin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use [WP Native Dashboard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/). But I just tested it and it's not working. So I tested a plugin for you and I found one that really works, it's [English WordPress Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/english-wp-admin/), after you activate it you will see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkQ2X.png), you click on Switch to English and it will update your dashboard Language, mine was Spanish and it changed to English as expected.

[image]

Comment: I installed this plugin, WP Native, but only option I see is to activate and not a place to change settings.

Comment: @NatalieRucando I just update the answer, sorry about that. Use: English WordPress Admin

Comment: I installed English Wordpress Admin and it works so far. Only problem it has is when you click view site or view store and your are viewing your frontend of website it keeps the admin bar across the top in the translated language.

Comment: I added a screenshot in my original post. Thank you for the suggestion of these 2 plugins.

Comment: The thing is that when you are viewing the frontend you are no longer on the dashboard/backend so it is normal that it happens... now your question would be how to show some sections of my frontend in a language and some other in another language... I think you can edit the po and mo files using Poedit, changing those strings on the admin bar back to English.

Comment: Thank you for everything! I will try that as well!

Comment: Ok, if that solved your question, don't forget to mark the answer as correct so other people can do directly to that.

Answer (score 5):

Since v 4.7, WP has a User specific language setting for admin area. You can find language field under Users>Your profile.

Comment: I cannot find that option, I am using WP 4.9.4. [What I see](https://i.imgur.com/wtuD6QV.png)

Comment: That's strange I have that option under Toolbar. However doesn't affect anything for me.

Comment: @Castiblanco Once you change your site language to non English for instance Chinese, you can see the language setting under your profile.